# How should I store this data for future expandability?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm wanting to create a database that stores some data about hardware. I also plan on using the Flot bar chart to retrieve and display the statistics.

What I'm wanting to do is store things like this:

broken hard drive, broken screen, broken case

With a checkbox indicating yes or no to update it via a php form.

The issue for me is that I want to be able to (in the future) add additional items to this list, so I want to know the best way to go about this. Right now I have a separate column for each trait in a database, but its nearly impossible to group things together to get usable data out.

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO! This is not a specific question. Here, at this site you ask specific questions, and not ask someone to code something for you. Also, go ahead and check YouTube for some tutorials on PHP & MySQL.

Comment: I actually have it coded already, but maybe I was misleading with my question. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using the following select statement.

```
SELECT sum(hd) as 'HD', sum(screen) as 'Screen' FROM incident
```

It took me a minute, but I remember that everything stored in the columns are either a 1 or a 0, so summing each column would yield exactly as desired.

I was then able to utilize the following code to make it formatted the way I needed:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        $incidentbytypeArray[] = array(
        $col,
        $val
);
        }
}
$incidentbytype = json_encode($incidentbytypeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP, MySQL would be what I would use. You can use the MySQL Workbench to visually develop how your differing tables link together and the Workbench will even create a build script to setup your database and tables.

As for expand-ability, you can then add columns or delete when necessary using the command given below if you later decide you want to re-design your tables:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Here is the PHP example to the MySQL extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php

Comment: I actually have it already built and setup, I'm just feeling that I'm going the wrong direction with this. As mentioned, every current option has a column assigned to it, which works great when it comes to updating via my php script - its super easy. I'm trying to see if there is a better way to do it.
Right now I'm needing to get the data in a presentable format to use with Flot tables, but with each column being separate, my data doesnt turn out nice. Example:

Comment: `SELECT hd,screen,bag FROM incident WHERE hd=1 OR screen=1 OR bag=1 AND (incidentdate <= DATE('2016-6-30') AND incidentdate >= DATE('2015-7-01'));`

I really need to get a count separately of when HD=1, Screen=1, and Bag=1. But I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

I've also tried this: `SELECT count(hd) as 'hdtotal', count(screen) as 'screentotal' , count(bag) as 'bagtotal' FROM incident WHERE hd=1 OR screen=1 OR bag=1 AND (incidentdate <= DATE('2016-6-30') AND incidentdate >= DATE('2015-7-01')) GROUP BY hd,screen,bag; `

Which gets me closer, but still doesnt return the data i'd like.